# Do Microsoft charge for a license when we add new Bot to Skype for Business?

Tags: azure, bots, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

I was trying to add a Chat Bot integrated with Knowledge Base to Skype For Business Channel.
I understand that, it will be added by the **Tenant Administrator**.

My question here is, as we are working on POC we need to understand that if we add any BOT, then it will be considered as a new User and incurr some license cost for that or it is just a Service User which will not incurr any cost?

I could not find more information on this. Can anybody please let me know the information for the same to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The costs can be split into two parts

- user of your [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) will cost you the same money like any other non-chatbot user. You'll of course need one user for each chatbot you may want to connect to your network.
- your [Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) will be charged the same way like any non Skype for Business (S4B) chatbot - [See here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service/)